# WP Admin Bar shown at the bottom

Tags: admin-bar

Suddenly, while I was working, the admin bar (that by default appears at the top) has appeared on the bottom of the page and it is unstyled, it is simply a list of links one below the other.

I've checked both header.php and footer.php and all seems to be at the right place (wp_head() and wo_footer()).

I'm using the last stable version of WordPress (3.1.3).

What could be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The admin bar's markup is added to the bottom of the page by default.  Then the admin bar is moved to the top of the page using CSS.  There are a couple of different reasons for this, but they're not important at the moment.

From the sounds of things, your browser just isn't loading the admin bar's stylesheet.  I'd recommend trying the following:

- Reloading the page with CTRL+F5 to force the browser to refresh the cache
- Use Firebug or some other kind of debugging tool to make sure `/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.css` is referenced by the page and loading correctly

Without knowing exactly what you changed while you were working and without seeing your actual site, this is the best I can recommend ...

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a CSS or JS conflict. Try deactivating the plugins one by one and see if it works.